# xslt translate of multiple characters

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, translate

I am trying to translate multiple characters into an 'X' or a ' '.
If the character is a 1,C,G it should be an 'X' else it's a ' '.

Currently I have this:

```
<xsl:variable name="correctedReturn">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(correctedReturn,'1','X')" />
</xsl:variable>
```

This translate any 1's into X's but not anything else.  I have tried to have multiple translate but it wasn't allowing me to have multiple translates in one variable.  Any help would be nice,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the character is a 1,C,G it should be an 'X' else it's a ' '.

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(correctedReturn,'1CG','XXX')" />
```

This will translate "1", "C" and "G" to "X". I am not sure what exactly you mean by "*else it's a ' '.*"  Here, all other characters will be left unmodified. If you really want to remove them altogether, you would have to do something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(correctedReturn, translate(correctedReturn, '1CG', ''), ''), '1CG','XXX')"/>
```

This would take a string of "ABCDEFGG12345" and return "XXXX".

Of course, if you have a list of all other allowed characters, this could be simpler.

Comment: But i need everything else to turn into ' ' blank spaces.  so if I passed in T -> it would be blank.